# what is the difference between Mocha and Supertest?

Tags: node.js, tdd, mocha.js, supertest

I'm a NodeJs beginner. Anyway, I want to create an application starting by tests, like TDD approach.

What is the difference between Mocha and Supertest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mocha` is a test framework.

> Mocha is a feature-rich JavaScript test framework running on Node.js and in the browser, making asynchronous testing simple and fun.

`supertest` is a module for testing API.

> Provides a high-level abstraction for testing HTTP, while still allowing you to drop down to the lower-level API provided by superagent.